# Using %f with strftime() in Python to get microseconds

Tags: python, time, strftime

I'm trying to use strftime() to microsecond precision, which seems possible using %f (as stated [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)). However when I try the following code:

```
import time
import strftime from time

print strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

...I get the hour, the minutes and the seconds, but %f prints as %f, with no sign of the microseconds. I'm running Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu, so it should be fine and %f should be supported (it's supported for 2.6 and above, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can use datetime's strftime function to get this. The problem is that time's strftime accepts a timetuple that does not carry microsecond information.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Not if you want to use `%z`

Comment: @Vallentin pretty sure it's the opposite! `datetime` [supports the `%z` directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) while [time doesn't appear to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

Comment: Both support `%z` in Python 3 :-) [here's datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and then [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: Ohh you're right. I missed it on datetime since it wasn't at the bottom, like on the table for time. :P

Comment: note the `from datetime import datetime`.  If you just do `import datetime` you will have to use `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")`

Answer (score 40):

You are looking at the wrong documentation. The `time` module [has different documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

You can use the `datetime` module [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
'12:19:40.948000'
```

Comment: Here's the link to the datetime module's documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thanks for the post. Why is there a datetime and time module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479777/difference-between-datetime-vs-time-modules

Answer (score 16):

With Python's `time` module you can't get microseconds with `%f`.

For those who still want to go with `time` module only, here is a workaround:

```
now = time.time()
mlsec = repr(now).split('.')[1][:3]
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.{} %Z".format(mlsec), time.localtime(now))
```

You should get something like **2017-01-16 16:42:34.625 EET** (yes, I use milliseconds as it's fairly enough).

To break the code into details, paste the below code into a Python console:

```
import time

# Get current timestamp
now = time.time()

# Debug now
now
print now
type(now)

# Debug strf time
struct_now = time.localtime(now)
print struct_now
type(struct_now)

# Print nicely formatted date
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", struct_now)

# Get miliseconds
mlsec = repr(now).split('.')[1][:3]
print mlsec

# Get your required timestamp string
timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.{} %Z".format(mlsec), struct_now)
print timestamp
```

For clarification purposes, I also paste my Python 2.7.12 result here:

```
>>> import time
>>> # get current timestamp
... now = time.time()
>>> # debug now
... now
1484578293.519106
>>> print now
1484578293.52
>>> type(now)
<type 'float'>
>>> # debug strf time
... struct_now = time.localtime(now)
>>> print struct_now
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=16, tm_min=51, tm_sec=33, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=16, tm_isdst=0)
>>> type(struct_now)
<type 'time.struct_time'>
>>> # print nicely formatted date
... print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", struct_now)
2017-01-16 16:51:33 EET
>>> # get miliseconds
... mlsec = repr(now).split('.')[1][:3]
>>> print mlsec
519
>>> # get your required timestamp string
... timestamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.{} %Z".format(mlsec), struct_now)
>>> print timestamp
2017-01-16 16:51:33.519 EET
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the work

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

It will print

`HH:MM:SS.microseconds` like this e.g `14:38:19.425961`

Answer (score 5):

You can also get microsecond precision from the `time` module using its `time()` function.
(`time.time()` returns the time in seconds since epoch. Its fractional part is the time in microseconds, which is what you want.)

```
>>> from time import time
>>> time()
... 1310554308.287459   # the fractional part is what you want.


# comparision with strftime -
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from time import time
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%f"), time()
... ('287389', 1310554310.287459)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for all your help. I've managed to get things working, though found an odd bug that means microseconds don't appear when running the script as sudo on a particular cset, but do if I log in as sudo before trying to run it on a particular cset. Odd.

Answer (score 5):

When the "%f" for micro seconds isn't working, please use the following method:

```
import datetime

def getTimeStamp():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    return dt.strftime("%Y%j%H%M%S") + str(dt.microsecond)
```

Comment: This won't work if the dt.microsecond has less than 6 digits.

Comment: This was the only solution that actually worked for me.  In Jython on Windows %f seems to always print a literal %f.  
I wanted milliseconds so used str(dt.microsecond)[0:3]

Comment: str(dt.microsecond)[0:3] might produce a wrong result (e.g. 300 microseconds are 0.300 milleseconds, but it will print 300!)

Comment: "%03d"%int(dt.microsecond/1000) -> this prints the millseconds and not microseconds

Answer (score 0):

If you want an integer, try this code:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s%f")[:13])
```

Output:

```
1545474382803
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed, try this:

```
def _timestamp(prec=0):
    t = time.time()
    s = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(t))
    if prec > 0:
        s += ("%.9f" % (t % 1,))[1:2+prec]
    return s
```

Where `prec` is precision -- how many decimal places you want.
Please note that the function does not have issues with leading zeros in fractional part like some other solutions presented here.