# Difference between Python datetime vs time modules

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to figure out the differences between the `datetime` and `time` modules, and what each should be used for.

I know that `datetime` provides both dates and time.  What is the use of the `time` module?

Examples would be appreciated and differences concerning timezones would especially be of interest.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The `time` module is principally for working with Unix time stamps; expressed as a floating point number taken to be seconds since the Unix epoch.  the `datetime` module can support many of the same operations, but provides a more object oriented set of types, and also has some limited support for time zones.

Comment: Further, what are the differences between `time` and `datetime.time`?

Comment: Would be nice to detail properties like if it's realtime/monotonic. Like in the POSIX standard you have: CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_THREAD, etc...
On POSIX clocks see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic

Answer (score 40):

## Stick to `time` to prevent DST ambiguity.

Use exclusively the system `time` module instead of the `datetime` module to [**prevent ambiguity issues with daylight savings time (DST)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561396/2192488).

Conversion to any time format, including local time, is pretty easy:

```
import time
t = time.time()

time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z', time.localtime(t))
'2019-05-27 12:03 CEST'

time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z', time.gmtime(t))
'2019-05-27 10:03 GMT'
```

`time.time()` is a floating point number representing the time in seconds since the system epoch. `time.time()` is ideal for unambiguous time stamping.

If the system additionally runs the [network time protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) dæmon, one ends up with a pretty solid time base.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) of the `time` module.

Comment: In your example, you use `time.localtime()`, which of course does have DST baked in. If we're going to be purists, shouldn't we use `time.gmtime()` instead? :)

Comment: @Seamus Simply testing both commands in `ipython` shows that `time.gmtime()` yields a tuple, whereas `time.time()` gives the [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as a single decimal value of seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 UTC, Thursday, 1 January 1970. The function `time.localtime(t)` converts the epoch time to a local time tuple. So, the answer to your question is «no».

Comment: Is there a way to add days to a time object ? with datetime there's the timedelta(days=6) method.

Comment: @NehemiasHerrera `t = time.time()` is a floating point number representing the time in seconds since the system epoch. Hence, one can simply add or substract 86400 seconds for every day; `t += 86400`

Comment: To all those that will say "Just use `datetime` like the others": this is the **only** way to read time in really old python versions (i'm talking about even 2.1 and 2.2!) or when generally `datetime` is **not available**. Thank you @SergeStroobandt

Answer (score 5):

The time module can be used when you just need the time of a particular record - like lets say you have a seperate table/file for the transactions for each day, then you would just need the time. 
However the time datatype is usually used to store the time *difference* between 2 points of time.

This can also be done using datetime, but if we are only dealing with time for a particular day, then time module can be used.

Datetime is used to store a particular data and time for a record. Like in a rental agency. The due date would be a datetime datatype.

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed that `time` is more precise than `datetime` with an extra digit.

```
import time as tm
from datetime import datetime as dt
restime = tm.time()
resdtime = dt.timestamp(dt.now())
print("TIME:".rjust(10," "),restime)
print("DATETIME:".rjust(10," "),resdtime)
```

Output

```
     TIME: 1637357103.7650678
 DATETIME: 1637357103.765067
```

Comment: Before you shoot me down... I know it doesn't run at the exact time... but try iterating it afew times... it actually has another digit.

Comment: What you're seeing there is the output of datetime's `__str__` implementation, which doesn't necessarily demonstrate the precision of the representations. It is correct that `datetime`s are limited to microsecond precision, but if you need to be more precise than that, you probably want to use `time.time_ns` or similar. `time.time()` is converted to a float, which loses precision -- even though you may see extra digits, you may not be gaining actual precision.