# Python : INPUT a microtime float, RESULT a formatted datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time, floating-point

I'm so confused with the Python time and datetime methods. Can someone maybe help me?

I just want to achieve a conversion from a microtime Float to a formatted string in this format:

```
mt = 1342993416.0
start_time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

// Some time or datetime magic here..

OUTPUT >> The file's date is: 2012-07-23 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the  [`.fromtimestamp()` class method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> mt = 1342993416.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mt)
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 22, 23, 43, 36)
```

then use the [`strftime` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format the output:

```
>>> start_time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mt).strftime(start_time_format)
'2012-07-22 23:43:36'
```

You can *also* use the [`time.strftime` function](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime(start_time_format, time.localtime(mt))
'2012-07-22 23:43:36'
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I'm sorry for the stupidity, but sometimes I can make such complex stuff, and sometimes and can't even manage to get the minor things to work.. Silly me :P. Thank you good sir :)

Comment: For the curious, here's a question that explains some of the differences between datetime and time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479777/difference-between-datetime-vs-time-modules

Comment: Thank you Lenna, I will surely look into that for future projects :)