# Format time string in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-3.3

I am trying to get current local time as a string in the format: year-month-day hour:mins:seconds. Which I will use for logging. By my reading of the documentation I can do this by:

```
import time
'{0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(time.localtime())
```

However I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`time.localtime` returns `time.struct_time` which does not support strftime-like formatting.

Pass [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object which support strftime formatting. (See [`datetime.datetime.__format__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__))

```
>>> import datetime
>>> '{0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
'2014-02-07 11:52:21'
```

Comment: is there any downside to using datetime.datetime instead of time?

Comment: OK, I see there differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479777/difference-between-datetime-vs-time-modules, datetime is more suited to my needs, thanks!

Comment: Try this too:
f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"

Comment: @Kieveli, The question is tagged `python-3.3`. f-string syntax is available in Python 3.6+. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108615/2225682) already mentioned f-string. :)

Answer (score 28):

And for newer versions of Python (3.6+, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ purely for completeness), you can use the newer string formatting, ie.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

f'{today:%Y-%m-%d}'
> '2018-11-01'
```

Answer (score 26):

You can alternatively use [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
time.strftime('{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `0:` is superfluous for `strftime`. +1