# Are these two formatting date methods really equivalent?

Tags: python, datetime, time

It seems that:

```
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#2017-01-12 10:46:57

datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#2017-01-12 10:46:57
```

are equivalent. When I read many questions/answers here, or tutorials or documentation, some of them use the former, some the latter.

**Are they 100% equivalent? When to prefer the one or the other?**

*PS: [the latter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today) seems to be equivalent to `datetime.date.fromtimestamp(time.time())`, but is this equivalent to `time.strftime(...)`?*

Answer (score 1):

The former seems faster? and [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479777/difference-between-datetime-vs-time-modules)

```
import time
import datetime
%timeit time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
%timeit datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.02 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 µs per loop
```