# How to compare DateTime object with an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I compare an object datetime.datetime.now().time() with an integer like 12?

I need to make an if condition, which checks whether the time of day is before 12PM or after 12PM and take corresponding action.

Comment: time objects have attributes which correspond hour, minute, second, microsecond, and timezone. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: you don't. You create a datetime object to compare instead:

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now().time()
b = datetime.time(12, 00, 00, 000000)
if a < b:
     print("Do x here")
else:
      print("Do y here")
```

Comment: No, it wasn't. I just figured it out by myself thanks to @R. Arctor's comment. And I will select the answer with the most votes (currently it's still a tie).

Comment: I see…well, technically, this code does not answer the question because it isn't comparing a `datetime` to an integer.

Comment: It does: you can't compare an integer with an datetime object. None of the other answers do that too. AFAIK, it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

```
d = datetime.datetime.now().time()
if d.hour > 12:
...
```

Comment: Is this better than the object comparison?

Comment: I've read that Python specially uses the datetime object, because it's the best way to compare time.

Comment: This does _not_ check to see if the time is after 12 pm, it checks if it's 1 pm or later — in other words, 12:01 pm is after 12 pm, but just checking the current hour won't tell you that...

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily checked using `.strftime("%p")`. Just have a look into below example.

> Based on your area time may differ but still you can test it for different timezones. Check **pytz** for that.

If you get

1. **PM**, that means, it's after 12 PM inclusive (and before midnight)
2. **AM**, that means, it's before 12 PM (and from midnight onwards)

> Example code:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now() 
print(now) # 2019-10-04 22:11:46.655252
print(now.strftime("%p")) # PM
print(now.time().strftime("%p")) # PM
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from above mentioned solutions, you could also do this:

```
import time
d = time.localtime()
if d.tm_hour > 12 && d.tm_sec>0:
   ...
```

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479777/difference-between-python-datetime-vs-time-modules) that discuss why using `time` module could be better than `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

The class datetime.time() has an hour attribute that you can use for your purpose.

```
import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if datetime_object.hour >= 12:
    print("Wow it's after 12 pm")
else:
    print("Wow it's before 12 pm")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a `datetime` instance with an integer *directly*, but you can convert one to an integer by first using the [`timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method to convert it to a floating-point value, and then converting that to an integer with the built-in [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function.

In the code below, an integer representing noon on the current day is created, and then that's compared to an integer representing the current date and time.

Since this requires one or more intermediate steps, it would probably be more efficient to just create a `datatime` object representing 12 pm on the current day and compare that to current date and time (as you do in your own answer).

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
noon = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=12)

noon_today = round(noon.timestamp())  # Convert to integer.
now_as_int = round(now.timestamp())

if now_as_int < noon_today:
     print("before noon")
else:
     print("noon or later")
```