# Drop hours and minutes in datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime

This is my first experience with Python. I am trying to determine how long it take for my code to run. Here is what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
startTime = datetime.now()
#Some code
t = datetime.now() - startTime
print t.strftime("%S.%f")
```

But it gives me this error:

```
'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

What should I do? I found this [example on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677332/using-f-with-strftime-in-python-to-get-microseconds/6677382#6677382) that is supposed to work and followed it:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
>>'12:19:40.948000'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime.now()` returns a `datetime.datetime` object (which has a `strftime` method).

However, when you subtract two such objects, you get a `datetime.deltatime` object (which does not have a `strftime` method).

You could achieve the result you are looking for like this:

```
print t.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to get seconds.

```
>>> start_time = datetime.now()
>>> t = datetime.now() - start_time
>>> t.total_seconds()
4.303854
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ipython or the Jupyter notebook, there is a built in magic function [`%time`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-time) to do such timing:

```
from time import sleep

%%time
sleep(1)

CPU times: user 336 µs, sys: 520 µs, total: 856 µs
Wall time: 1 s
```