# How to get ISO8601 string for datetime with milliseconds instead of microseconds in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-3.5, iso8601

Given the following datetime:

```
d = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 9, 8, 19, 16, 999578, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, 7200))
```

d.isoformat() results in the string:

```
'2018-10-09T08:19:16.999578+02:00'
```

How can I get a string with milliseconds instead of microseconds:

```
'2018-10-09T08:19:16.999+02:00'
```

strftime() will not work here: %z returns 0200 istead of 02:00 and has only %f to get microseconds, there is no placeholder for milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using %f with strftime() in Python to get microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677332/using-f-with-strftime-in-python-to-get-microseconds)

Comment: strftime(): %z returns 0200 istead of 02:00 and has only %f to get microseconds, no placeholder for milliseconds.

Comment: formatting time data in datetime object to strings is still using `str.format()`, if you can get microseconds & millisecs from datetime object you can format the strings representations in any way `str.format` can do. `strftime()` is exactly the provided method for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If timezone without colon is ok, you can use

```
d = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 9, 8, 19, 16, 999578, 
                      tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, 7200))
s = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + d.strftime('%z')
# '2018-10-09T08:19:16.999+0200'
```

For colon, you need to split the timezone and add it there yourself. `%z` does not produce `Z` either for UTC.

---

And Python 3.6 supports `timespec='milliseconds'` so you should shim this:

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
    def milliseconds_timestamp(d):
        return d.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')

except TypeError:
    def milliseconds_timestamp(d):
        z = d.strftime('%z')
        z = z[:3] + ':' + z[3:]
        return d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + z
```

Given the latter definition in Python 3.6,

```
>>> milliseconds_timestamp(d) == d.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
True
```

with

```
>>> milliseconds_timestamp(d)
'2018-10-09T08:19:16.999+02:00'
```

Comment: Colon is important and it has to run with python 3.5.

Comment: @cytrinox then my latter excerpt

Answer (score 0):

on 3.10 (maybe earlier, too), you can do it on a one-liner

```py
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-6), name="CST")
>>> now_tz = now.replace(tzinfo=tz)
>>> now_tz.isoformat("#","milliseconds")
'2023-03-02#11:02:07.592-06:00'
```